# Hotfix vs Patch vs Update - Game development

Tags: patch, definition, hotfix

I was wondering if someone could help me sort this out.
Hotfix vs Patch vs Update.

I have look around the website but it only mentions about programs.
From what I understood,
Hotfix is to fix a certain bug and not always will be public announcement.
Patch is fixing few bugs and its public announcement.
Update is adding new content (as well as fixing bugs)

but isnt Patch used for new content as well?

I'm a bit confused with those terms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HotFix come in the form of a configuration change to workaround a problem or to fix a running application or server with minimal down time.

Patch is typically an update to existing code and delivered in binary form to fix a specific issue, bug or compatibility problems.

Updates can be used for enhancement or to bring an application up to date (and possibly contain multiple fixes rolled up).